# vue3 componentAPI, I have a question about object manipulation

Tags: vuejs3

I am new to vue3.
First, please look at the image below.
[image]

The code for this image is below.

```
    const category = ref('')

    onMounted(() => {

        axios.get('/api/top')
            .then((res) => {

            category.value = res.data
            console.log(category) // line12
            console.log(category.value) // line13
            console.log(category.value[0]) // line14
            console.log(category.value[0].title) // line15
        })
    })
```

I don't know why console.log(category.value[0]) equall Proxy {id: 13, pos: null, title: 'dfgh', created_at: '2022-11-02T13:52:25.000000Z', updated_at: '2022-11-02T13:52:25.000000Z'}.

I respond to one record in the server side and catch this record in the browser.

please tell me value[0] meaning.

Thank you!

I want to display title of record but, in template tag {{ category.value[0].title }} occur error. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In the template, you should check `category.value[0]` is `undefined` or not. Because before fetching the data, your `category.value` possible `undefined`

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you're saying.
I would like to you explain in another way.

Comment: The initial value of `category` is `ref('')`. So accessing `category.value[0].title` will fail definitely. You should check `undefined` before accessing it like that `{{ category && category[0] ? category[0].title : '' }}` In the template, you don't need to add `.value` to access a Ref

Comment: I understand about 80 % of what you are saying and {{ category && category[0] ? category[0].title : '' }} fix the issue.
thank you!
please Let me ask you one more question.
in {{ category && category[0]  ? category[0].title : ''}}, why do we need category in front of &&??

Comment: It is future-proof. Imagine in some cases `res.data === null`. So the `category` will be `null`. So you should always check if it is null or not first

Comment: `category && category[0]` means checking `category` and `category[0]` are null or not

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I understand category meaning.

Comment: `category.value[0]` is a Proxy because Vue makes values _deeply_ reactive: all objects in the value become proxies, so that accesses and mutations can be tracked.